# Laravel is giving \ sign before every response in api

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys when i try to get an response from the routes in Laravel im getting the \ sign before every response.
This is an example how my route looks like:

```
Route::post('a1',function ()
{
    return response()->json('a1');

});
```

and this is the response via Postman:

```
\"a1"
```

any idea where to find the bug ?
thanks.

Comment: More than likely you have a stray \ in your template or view somewhere. Check the HTML.

Comment: Since it's a Laravel API route just returning json, you're going to have to search a little deeper, since it's not touching template/views. Look in your routes file and your index.php for any stray slashes. If it's not there, you're going to have to really start searching all of the PHP files. Usually it would be at the very beginning of the file

Comment: Remove the `vendor` directory and do a fresh `composer install`, in case you accidentally put it in one of the thousands of files there. If that doesn't solve things, you'll need to look in your app for a wayward \ at the beginning of a file.

Answer (score 0):

check index.php and middlewares, smth here you send \

Comment: There are other potential locations, like the service providers in `app/Providers`.